Existence of critical trajectories of quadratic differential
Let $P$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients. A horizontal trajectory is a curve in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $P(z) \, dz^2 > 0$, i.e. a solution $\gamma$ to the differential equation $$P(\gamma(t)) \left( \frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt} \right)^2 = 1$$
A critical trajectory is a horizontal trajectory whose start and endpoint is either a zero of $P$ or $\infty$ (viewed as a point in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$). My question is: given two zeros of $P$ when can I tell if there is a critical trajectory between them? And is there any way to tell if $P$ has any zeros on the trajectory in between my endpoints?
One (trivial) necessary condition for the existence of a critical trajectory between $z_1$ and $z_2$, where these are zeros of $P$, is that
$$\int_{z_1}^{z_2} \sqrt{P(w)} \, dw \in \mathbb{R}$$
but is this sufficient?

According to your expression, I do not see how $\gamma(t)$ can be a zero of $P$ in such a $t_0$ or so we need $\dfrac{d\gamma(t)}{dt} \to \infty$ when $t \to t_0$.

@EDX If $P$ has a simple zero at $\gamma(t_0)$ and $\gamma(t) \sim c (t-t_0)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ as $t \to t_0$ then I think things should work. Anyway, one can always reparametrise the contour to get the RHS of the differential equation to be any positive function.

Why $2/3$ ? in exponent ?

@EDX This is what you find if you solve $\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt} = (\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_0))^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. I should have written $\gamma(t) - \gamma(t_0) \sim c (t-t_0)^\frac{2}{3}$ in my previous reply.

Where does the equation comes from ?

@EDX It comes from approximating $P(z)$ around a simple zero $z_0$ as $P(z) \sim c(z-z_0)$ and substituting this into the differential equation.

K it makes sense
